# ActionScript only project in Flash Builder with DocumentClass?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

this little tutorial shows nicely how to setup an ActionScript only project in flashbuilder:
http://ted.onflash.org/2010/03/air-apps-using-actionscript-only.php

however - it relies on nativeWindow class.

How can I do it without? I want to create in flashbuilder a project that is as if I'd use the FlashIDE with a Document Class (or let's say, I try to modify an ActionScript only project which uses the NativeWindow class such that it does not use the NativeWindow class).

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is about an AIR application. If you want to create an Actionscript only project, you can do so in Flash Builder using 'New'->'ActionScript Project'. Flash Builder will then ask you for a name, and will automatically create a class with the same name. That class is more or less the same as the Document Class in Flash.

Comment: I'm talking about an ActionScript only project that compiles to an AIR application ( the same as if you'd create an air application in the FlashIDE, just to do it with Flash Builder).

Comment: Then you choose New Flex Project. In the window that appears then, you can choose "Desktop" as the application type. Then it will run in Adobe AIR. Then click next until you get to the window that you define your main class in. It defaults to <your project name>.mxml, but you can change the extension into .as so you won't have to write mxml if you don't want to.

Comment: Looking at that tutorial, they say about the same thing as my last comment. If you want to use AIR you cannot get around using NativeWindows because that is what AIR apps are about: applications in windows on the desktop.